# How to use index to mark unbound variable in prolog?

Tags: variables, prolog

how can I mark all the unbound variable to number? For example :

```
exists(_G1234...all(_G2345...
```

changes to

```
exists(1 ... all(2...
```

("..."menas code which not important)

(exists and all are compound type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [term_variables/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2) to get the unbound variables and then number them.

```
index_mark_unbound(Term):-
  term_variables(Term, Vars),
  range(Vars, 1).

range([], _).
range([Value|Vars], Value):-
  succ(Value, NValue),
  range(Vars, NValue).
```

Test:

```
 ?- Term=exists(A,all(_,B),A), index_mark_unbound(Term).
Term = exists(1, all(2, 3), 1),
A = 1,
B = 3
```